# How to pass data from Form to mapDispatchToProps in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react, trying to build a Login form, able to extract username and password from the form. But I'm having trouble trying to pass this to mapDispatchToProps to dispatch it to the Backend.

How would I go about obtaining the username and password from "values" to actually passing it to the mapDispatchToProps?

I get an error saying the "onAuth" cannot be accessed outside the function.

Here's the code snippet:

```js
const NormalLoginForm = (props) => {


  const onFinish = values => {
    const onAuth = (values.username, values.password) // This is where the error is occuring
    console.log('Success:', values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = errorInfo => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };

  return (
  
        <Form
            {...layout}
            name="basic"
            initialValues={{
                remember: true,
            }}
            onFinish={onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            >
            <Form.Item
                label="Username"
                name="username"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your username!',
                },
                ]}
            >
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                rules={[
                {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your password!',
                },
                ]}
            >
                <Input.Password />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                 Submit
                </Button>
                <NavLink 
                    style={{marginRight: '10px'}}
                    to='/signup/'> Signup
                </NavLink>

            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
  );
};



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NormalLoginForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like mapDispatchToProps is already setup correctly, you just need to call the function it created.

```
const onFinish = values => {
  props.onAuth(values.username, values.password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace const `onAuth = (values.username, values.password)` with `props.onAuth(values.username, values.password)`.

Whatever parameters we define in `mapDispatchToProps` or `mapStateToProps` come as `props` in the component.